# Extracting XML Elements from Java Object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

How can i extract an xml element from a java object. for example i have an object of java.lang.Object that contain xml file content at below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<custom:a ...>
 <custom:b...>
   .....
 </custom:b>
</custom:a>
```

i want to extract `<custom:b..>` element. please guide me!

Comment: Is the object itself a string? Does the object contain a string where the xml is?

Comment: _How_ does your `Object` contain XML?  The object must be some other subclass of `Object`, and without knowing that nobody can help you.  It could be a `String` containing the serialized XML, or it could be a parsed element tree.

Comment: In any case, there are literally hundreds of questions about this very subject on SO already.

Comment: i can convert his object to string using this code     String_content= new String((byte[])resource.getContent());    resource is a xml file for example wsdl document

Comment: i confused that which way is better for me! because i want extract an element by QName (custom:a). i create a dom.document of my object but it return element by tagname. i dont know how return element by QName in it!